# Issue with Writing to the Flash of STM32L4R5

Tags: c++, stm32

I'm using an S-record file to update the MCU Firmware Application of STM32L4R5 through a Bootloader.
Most Row Addresses of the S-records in the file are at the 16-byte offset of a flash row (e.g. 0x08010010, 0x08010020, 0x08010030) but there are some at 8-byte and 12-bite offset, like this:

S3150808F7200000000000C0153F00000000DCCFD135FE
**S30D0808F730E416F87F0100000049
S3090808F738E5010108C8
S3090808F73CC1010108E8**
S3150808F74000000010002001000040100002004000E0

The Bootloader is writing to the 16-byte flash row as a Double Word at the order of receiving the S-records, padding the empty spaces with 0xFF to keep them not programmed.
In this case writing to the flash row at address 0x0808F730 takes place three times, like this:

**0808F730 E416F87F01000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
0808F730 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE5010108FFFFFFFF
0808F730 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC1010108**

However, address 0x0808F730 reads back as:

**0808F730 E416F87F01000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF**

As a result the Application doesn't start and enters the Error Handler instead.
I dumped the flash for both the operational application programmed with the debugger and this one programmed by the Bootloader. This row shows the only difference.

Does anybody know if a Flash row only accepts a single writing to a flash row?
How is this supposed to work, am I missing anything?

Comment: I am assuming that the FLASH_SR is clear of all errors, correct?  Did all of your writes pass?

Comment: As long as you follow the correct alignment, size, and procedure for writing to the L4's embedded flash (Per the ref manual), it should write correctly as long as you are not crossing double-words (overlapping 8-byte intervals without erasing it first).

Answer (score 1):

### Update S-records file to use only 16-byte aligned writes

It's not uncommon for bootloaders to only accept writes to **16-byte** aligned addresses when writing to flash in order to reduce complexity in the bootloader. The solution is to post-process S-records to merge all non-aligned writes into a single write per aligned address.

##### MERGE 3 WRITES INTO 1

So for address `0x0808F730` merge the 3 S-records into 1 S-record

```
0808F730 E416F87F01000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 
0808F730 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE5010108FFFFFFFF 
0808F730 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC1010108
----------------------------------------- merge
0808F730 E416F87F01000000E5010108C1010108
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility. But I'm not using the embedded Bootloader. I have developed my Bootloader, which is directly writing a 16-byte data row to a specified Flash offset. If the Flash doesn't accept a second writing to the same row but the S-record file (Intel Hex file does the same) provides data at offsets less the 16 bytes, how is this supposed to work?

Comment: Change the order of the srecords and see if it changes the results.

Answer (score 1):

> The Bootloader is writing to the 16-byte flash row as a Double Word at the order of receiving the S-records, padding the empty spaces with 0xFF to keep them not programmed. In this case writing to the flash row at address 0x0808F730 takes place three times, like this:
> 0808F730 E416F87F01000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 0808F730 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE5010108FFFFFFFF 0808F730 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC1010108

If you request to write to the address 0x0808F730 after programming once, the double-word area needs to be in the erased-state (0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF) before programming again.  Just pack the data into a buffer and write in double-word increments.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the reason of this issue. Looks like a Flash row can be written only once. Probably this is associated with the ECC. What I did is combine the three short words coming with the S-record in a 16-byte word and write to that row at once.

Comment: An [STM32L4](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/91/e3/aa/26/e6/69/4f/de/STM32L4_Memory_Flash.pdf/files/STM32L4_Memory_Flash.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_Memory_Flash.pdf) can be erased; it can be re-written.  You got several good suggestions, including 
James Novorita's original comment 2 days ago: "As long as you follow the correct alignment, size, and procedure for writing to the L4's embedded flash (Per the ref manual), it should write correctly..."  I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you got it working.  That's what I had suspected.

Comment: Yes, your suspicions are correct.  Flash words are 72-bits long.  64-bit data, 8 bits of redundancy for the code.  ECC peripheral cues off of this as the word size.  As mentioned before, the 64-bit doubleword area needs to be in the erased state before the Embedded Flash peripheral allows writing again.